# Compatibility of right and left congruences modulo H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G = S_3$ and $H$ the subgroup $H$ = ⟨(23)⟩. And let $\rho_r$ and $\rho_l$ two relations right- and left-congruence mod $H$. I need to verify whether the two relations are compatible with the group operation. A compatible relation with the group operation is such that

$g_1 \,ρ\, g'_1,   g_2 \,ρ\, g_2'   ⇒   g_1g_2 \,ρ\, g'_1g'_2$

I don't understand how the author is deducing the non-compatibility from the fact that

$(123)(132) = id ∈ H   but  (13)(12) = (123) ∉ H  \quad \mathbf{1.0}$

I am able to show that $\rho_r \ne \rho_l$ since there are elements $ab$ such that $ab^{-1} \in H$  but $b^{-1}a \notin H$. But with (1.0) the author seems to be expressing a different additional fact.

Comment: Use `$\langle x\rangle$` for $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: Eventually I did like this: I've calculated left and right cosets and then applied the definition of compatibility to show that, $(13) \rho_r  (123), \quad (12) \rho_r (132) \quad⇒ \quad (13)(12) \rho_r  (123)(132)$. I'm not sure that's equivalent to what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have $(123)=(23)(13)$ and $(132)=(23)(12)$ and $g\,\rho_l\,e\iff g\in H$.